# How do I see examples on the ubuntu-sdk?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5

The Ubuntu developer website says:

> For a presentation of Ubuntu HTML5 widgets, check out the HTML5
>   Gallery App (installed by the ubuntu-html5-ui-toolkit-examples
>   package). You can launch the gallery by searching the Ubuntu
>   Applications scope for “Ubuntu HTML5 UI Gallery”.

But I cant find any examples on the ubuntu-sdk. I tried to search the Applications scope and after I tried to install the package, but my system (desktop) says it's already installed.

I need the code syntax for the text field widget. Obviously I would also like to see other (more) code examples.

I found the qmlscene app installed, but not the code for HTML5 examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the list of files of an installed `.deb` package:

```
dpkg -L ubuntu-html5-ui-toolkit-examples
```

`/usr/share/applications/ubuntu-html5-ui-gallery.desktop` file there describes the icon that will appear in the Applications scope. I can open `Ubuntu HTML5 UI Gallery` if I search for it in Dash.

To run it from terminal:

```
qmlscene /usr/share/ubuntu-html5-ui-toolkit/0.1/examples/ui-gallery/qml/main.qml
```

Example HTML code for TextInputs is in `/usr/share/ubuntu-html5-ui-toolkit/0.1/examples/widgets/TextInputs.html`.